# Convert two while loop code to java 8 stream code

Tags: java, while-loop, java-stream

I was using simple InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() but for one of the server it was giving 127.0.0.0 ip address, which was not expected ip address.
To get actual ip address from server, i am using now below code but want to make it simpler.
Can we make below code simper with java 8 stream code?

```
public static InetAddress getInetAddress() throws SocketException {
    
            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networkInterfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (networkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface ni = (NetworkInterface) networkInterfaces.nextElement();
                Enumeration<InetAddress> nias = ni.getInetAddresses();
                while (nias.hasMoreElements()) {
                    InetAddress ia = (InetAddress) nias.nextElement();
                    if (!ia.isLinkLocalAddress() && !ia.isLoopbackAddress() && ia instanceof Inet4Address) {
                        return ia;
                    }
                }
            }
    
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use [Collections.list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#list(java.util.Enumeration)) to convert the enumeration to `ArrayList` and then use `List's stream` and related Stream API functions to filter out unnecessary instances of `InetAddress` and select the first one matching the criteria:

```java
public static InetAddress getInetAddress() throws SocketException {
    return Collections
            .list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces())
            .stream() // Stream<NetworkInterface>
            .flatMap(ni -> Collections.list(ni.getInetAddresses()).stream()) // Stream<InetAddress>
            .filter(ia -> !ia.isLinkLocalAddress() && !ia.isLoopbackAddress() && ia instanceof Inet4Address)
            .findFirst()  // Optional<InetAddress>
            .orElse(null);
}
```